# Is it advisable to use a signature (query data hashed with a private key) as a nonce to avoid replay attacks?

Tags: security, cryptography

I'm building an API where each request query string contains the following:

- A timestamp
- A couple of data parameters
- A public key
- A signature (the data parameters and timestamp hashed with a private key)

When receiving a request, the server checks the timestamp and denies requests that are too old. The server also validates the signature.

Is it advisable to save the signature in a database for a while, to make sure that there are no replay attacks during the valid timeframe? This is clearly close to how a nonce works, but I'd be happy to hear your thoughts on the approach.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. Such a questions is much better suited for [security.se] (or even [crypto.se]).

Comment: I will keep this in mind in the future. Thank you for your thoughts, @ArtjomB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a pretty standard technique.

However, I would add a "nonce" field to the list. The reason is what happens if two legitimate requests are issued in the same second? Just storing the signature, you'd reject a valid request.

But if you let the client generate a 128+ bit nonce and include that in the request, then they could submit as many requests per second as they want.

Then, just maintain a list of seen nonces along with the timestamp. And you can purge that list based on the expiry of the timestamp.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the use case where several legitimate requests are issued in the same second. I will add a nonce to the API.